# gdal_calc - FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, gdal-calc

I use `gdal_calc` in the loop:

```
 for inp, out in zip(input, output):

    input_str = ''.join(inp)
    print input_str
    output_str = ''.join(out)
    print output_str


    gdal_calc = 'python gdal_calc.py --format GTiff -A '+input_str+' --outfile='+output_str+' --calc="10*log10(A) " --NoDataValue=0 --type=Int16'  
    os.system(gdal_calc)
```

Warning appears

`FutureWarning: comparison to`None`will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  myNDVs=1*numpy.logical_or(myNDVs==1, myval==myNDV[i])`

Does anyone know what the problem is?